# Argument cannot be null exception in google cloud messenger

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

We are using google cloud messenger for push notification. It was working fine few days before but suddenly it has started giving an exception.

Following is the stack trace

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument cannot be null   at
>   com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.nonNull(Sender.java:553)     at
>   com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.getString(Sender.java:534)   at
>   com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:365)     at
>   com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:261)    at
>   org.cdac.gist.restws.gcm.GCMSender.sendGCM(GCMSender.java:48)     at
>   org.cdac.gist.restws.handlers.GCMAndroidPushHandler.gcmSender(GCMAndroidPushHandler.java:156)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.cdac.gist.restws.security.ClickjackFilter.doFilter(ClickjackFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Following is my source code

```
public final static int sendGCM(final String title, final List<String> registrationID)  throws IOException{         
            int status = 0;
            Sender sender = new Sender(apiKey);

            Message message = new Message.Builder()
                // .collapseKey("1")
                .timeToLive(86400)//sets the time of 1 day for GCM to push notifications when android device is off, offline or unavailable
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("message", title)              
                .build();                        

            MulticastResult  result = sender.send(message, registrationID, 1);
            System.out.println("Result "+result);
                if(result == null){
                    throw new IOException("Could not send message");                    
                }else{
                    status = 1;
                }

                return status;  
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure but this was an [issue](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/7) way back and its resolved . You might wanna update your libs .

Comment: my push notification was working fine few days before, suddenly it has started giving an exception. if it is lib issue then how it was working before?

Comment: my current jar version is gcm-server-1.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to GCM support for up to 1,000 recipients for a single message

so I divided my registration ArrayList into 1000 equal parts and then I sent the message to GCM. Now I am able to send the push notification.

Following is my updated code

```
public final static int sendGCM(final String title, final List<String> registrationID)  throws IOException{         
        int status = 0;
        MulticastResult  result =null;


        for (int start = 0; start < registrationID.size(); start += 1000) {
            int end = Math.min(start + 1000, registrationID.size());
            List<String> sublist = registrationID.subList(start, end);
            System.out.println(sublist);
            Sender sender = new Sender(apiKey);

            Message message = new Message.Builder()
                // .collapseKey("1")
                .timeToLive(86400)//sets the time of 1 day for GCM to push notifications when android device is off, offline or unavailable
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("message", title)              
                .build();                        

            result = sender.send(message, sublist, 1);
            System.out.println("Result "+result);
        }
         if(result == null){
                throw new IOException("Could not send message");                    
            }else{
                status = 1;
            }
            return status;  
        }
```